# SWIFTUI Displaying JSON Data in ContentView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I have been having trouble displaying my JSON into my content view. I can decode the data and save it into a dictionary as I have printed and seen. However when its time to display it in ContentView with a ForEach. I'm getting this error *Cannot convert value of type '[String : String]' to expected argument type 'Binding'* Below is my code for my ContentView, Struct and ApiCall. I have read other solutions on stackoverflow and tried them all but they do not work.

```
struct ContentView: View { 

    @StateObject var api = APICALL()
    
    var body: some View {
        let country = api.storedData.countries
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(country.id, id: \.self) { country in
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Text("\(country.countries)")
                }
                
            }
            .onAppear {
                api.loadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My ApiCall class which loads the data, as well as the struct.

```
// MARK: - Country
struct Country: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var countries: [String: String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case countries = "countries"
    }
}

class APICALL: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var storedData = Country(countries: [:])
    
    func loadData() {
        let apikey = ""
        
        guard let url = URL(string:"https://countries-cities.p.rapidapi.com/location/country/list?rapidapi-key=\(apikey)") else {
            print("Your Api end point is Invalid")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Country.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.storedData.countries = response.countries
                        print(self.storedData.countries)
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

Any Point in the right direction would be absolutely helpful.

Comment: Don't you want to show the content of the field `countries` ? Thus you would write `Text("\(country.countries)")`

Comment: @jeandemeusy Hello There, I haave just inputed that in and the error I still get an error. I think it has something to do with my [String:String] correlation

Comment: What does the JSON look like that you need a `[String:String]` to hold it?

Comment: Some notes, ForEach takes an array as the first argument, not an id, you should be more careful with how you name your types, variables etc because the code is very confusing, you don't really need to keep the whole Country object for this, maybe your @Published property should only contain the values from the dictionary

Comment: @Yrb Here is an example of the JSON result: "{"countries":{"DM":"Dominica","GN":"Guinea","BV":"Bouvet Island"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you, I will certainly try this and get back to you. I know alot of my variables have similar names.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this approach to display your countries data:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var api = APICALL()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // -- here --
            ForEach(Array(api.storedData.countries.enumerated()), id: \.0) { index, country in 
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Text("\(country.key)   \(country.value)")
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                api.loadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can also use this, if you prefer:

```
    ForEach(api.storedData.countries.sorted(by: >), id: \.key) { key, value in
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Text("\(key)   \(value)")
        }
    }
```